# Prove that the following spaces are homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

Prove that the space obtained from the torus $R^2/Z^2$ by identifying every point x with -x is homeomorphic to the sphere.
I can see visually why this should be true but i am not sure how to write it down.

Comment: What is $-x $ for $x\in\Bbb R^2/\Bbb Z^2$? If $-x=-(x_1,x_2)+\Bbb Z^2$ provided $x=(x_1,x_2)+\Bbb Z^2$ then I don’t see that the identified space as a sphere because it has a boundary.

Comment: @AlexRavsky It's the quotient of the torus by the elliptic involution (projection of the antipodal map of the  plane) which is indeed the 2-sphere.